# Rails ActiveStorage: How to preview image stored in active storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using ActiveStorage to store images for the post. My model looks like this

```
class Post
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

I am able to save image in active storage. But I am not able to preview them. I am able to display download link and then view the image. My code looks like this

```
<% @post.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= link_to "View", image %>
<% end %>
```

But I want to display image rather than download link. So how can i preview the images ? I tried something like this and it didn't work

```
<% @post.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag(image) %>
<% end %>
```

I also tried installing `poppler` gem and tried like this, but this also didn't work.

```
<%= image_tag image.preview(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) %>
```

Update:

`<%= image_tag(image) %>` worked. I was not able to view the image because size of image was too big so I had to scroll down.

Comment: Can you check if the url of the image file (src attribute) and download link (href) are same? Also, if you can share what error you are getting OR if you are not getting any error, what is the resulting html for both cases (link vs image_tag)

Comment: @Ankit when using `<%= image_tag image.preview(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) `, I am getting `ActiveStorage::UnpreviewableError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= image_tag(image) %>` worked. I was not able to view the image because size of image was too big so I had to scroll down.